# Play sound when pressing keyboard shortcut in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to play a sound (from a sound file I have) when I press a shortcut in Windows 10. Is that possible ? Maybe using some third party software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a shortcut that contains a command-line to play an audio file.

You could use for example the excellent
[VLC for Windows](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html)
with a command-line such as (standard installation assumed):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I ncurses --play-and-exit "path-to-file"
```

This will play the file without showing a graphical interface and
VLC will terminate when finished.

Comment: nircmd can also play a sound. might be more elegant.

Comment: This works, though it is a bit slow to react (open the command line and all it seems). Any  improvement suggestions ?

Comment: @LPChip nircmd must also be called via command line, that has the same reactivity problem.